# building a floating number using c

Tags: c, floating-point

I have to input in three, a sign(+ or -),exponent and a significand(y.yyyyyy). Now i have to use these three parts to construct a float number. This program should deal with the property of normalized and denormalized but ignore the infinity and special case concept. I am not sure how to go about this program, if some one would be generous enough to give me a head start. PS- I am not so familiar with using C as a programming language, i have used a very few times.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a machine that writes your code for you.  If you're not familiar with C, it doesn't seem like this is a good way to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can build floating point numbers that way with something like:

```
char sign = '-';
int exponent = -3;
double significand = 27.5;

double value = significand * pow (10, exponent);
if (sign == '-') value = -value;
```

To get the significand as a floating point value (from a string), you can use repated multiplications by powers of ten.

But, since you're using C, why don't you just look into `atof` which does it all for you?

You can do something like:

```
char *sign = "-";
char *exponent = "-3";
char *significand = "27.5";

char buffer[100];
sprintf (buff, "%s%sE%s", sign, significand, exponent);
double value = atof (buffer);
```

Comment: thanks @paxdiablo i forgot to mention i cant use <math.h> could you let me what %s$sE%s do.

Comment: `atof` is in `stdlib.h`, not `math.h`. The `sprintf` (with new, corrected format) creates a string from the three components that `atof` can use, like "-27.5E-3".